# List of strings to array of NVPair

Tags: c#, arrays, string

Working with an API where I need to send a value over in an array of NVPairs, like the following:

```
new[]
{
    new[]
    {
        new NVPair
        {
            name = "email_address",
            value = "email1@email.com"
        }
    },
    new[]
    {
        new NVPair
        {
            name = "email_address",
            value = "email2@email.com"
        }
     }
}
```

I need to be able to create this (the value, or "email2@email.com") from a list of strings (that will be the email addresses).

Would anyone be able to provide some guidance?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: It's not really clear what you mean - what's your input data, and why are you building two single-element arrays, rather than one two-element array?

Comment: @JonSkeet - I need to take the list of emails (which are a string) and format them to an array of NVPairs.  If there's a more efficient way of doing it, I'd love that, but the code above is what I got to work hard-coded.  Does that help clarify?  Thanks!

Comment: @mmillican: Not really - you've got two values in each pair; where have those separate values come from? Do you already have the splitting part, if they're from a single string? And you still haven't explained why you've got an array of arrays...

Comment: @JonSkeet The array of arrays is in the API, so I don't have control over that.  The `name = "email_address"` is telling the API that I'm sending an email (as it could be a first name, last name, etc).  I would like to get my `List<string>` into the `value` of that NVPair.

Comment: @mmillican - Are you sure the API you are using is expecting an array of arrays that each only contain 1 `NVPair` element (as your example shows)? It seems a bit nonsensical to me.

Comment: @mmillican: Right, that's fair enough - it would have been helpful if your question had *stated* that you wanted "an array of arrays of NVPair" rather than "an array of NVPairs" then. Sample input data would have been useful, too. Still, hopefully my answer is what you're after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you really want an array of single-element arrays, I suspect you want:

```
var nvPairs = strings.Select(x => new[] { new NVPair("email_address", x) })
                     .ToArray();
```

This is also assuming that the `NVPair` type in question has a two-parameter constructor, taking the name and the value. If it doesn't, the query becomes uglier:

```
var nvPairs = strings.Select(x => new[] { new NVPair { name = "email_address",
                                                       value = x } })
                     .ToArray();
```

Note the `new[]` so that each element is transformed into a single-element array.

Another option which would at least work from a compile-time point of view is to create a single-element *outer* array, where its sole element was a multi-element array:

```
var nvPairs = new[] { strings.Select(x => new NVPair("email_address", x))
                             .ToArray() };
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want to create an array of `NVPair`s, rather than an array of single-element `NVPair` arrays, you can use Linq to achieve this:

```
using System.Linq;
...
var strings = new[] { "email1@email.com", "email2@email.com" };
var nvpairArray = strings.Select(s => new NVPair { name = "email_address", value = s }).ToArray();
```

**Update**

```
NVPair[][] nvpairArrayOfArrays = strings.Select(s => new NVPair[] { new NVPair { name = "email_address", value = s } }).ToArray();
```

Comment: That's what was going for, however I have one more twist.  Intellisense is saying it wants
`NVPair[][]` which the above doesn't quite return?

The joys of APIs :)

Comment: @mmillican: This is because you claimed you wanted an array of NVPairs, whereas `NVPair[][]` is an array of arrays of NVPairs. The joys of being precise about requirements :)

Comment: I've updated the answer to replicate what you had manually written.

Comment: @JonSkeet Thanks for the clarification.  I haven't seen something like this before, hence part of my confusion!  Testing your code above now though!

Comment: I probably should have mentioned I updated my answer a while ago.

Comment: @devdigital I apologize, I hadn't seen it earlier!

Comment: That's ok, Jon needs the rep :)